# Databricks Notebook Schedule

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-notebook

I have scheduled an ADB notebook to run on a schedule. Will the notebook run if the cluster is down? Right now the cluster is busy so unable to stop and try it out. Will the notebook start the cluster and run or would wait for the cluster to be up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're scheduling the notebook to run on the existing cluster, then cluster will be started if it's stopped.  But in reality, it's better to execute the notebook on the new cluster - there will be less chance of breaking things if you change library version or something like.  If you need to speedup the job execution you may look onto [instance pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/instance-pools/).